# Hide image with play button

Tags: javascript, css, hide

The play button image hides when I click it, how do I also have the green image hide?

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

Hide the green image after the play image is clicked.

Currently only the play image hides, how to I have the green image hide aftr the play image is clicked?

https://jsfiddle.net/075anu3x/

**css** green image

```
.video-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ShS6nAO.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

[image]

**javascript**

```
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const events = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function fadeVideoIn(cover) {
    hide(cover);
    const videoWrapper = document.querySelector(".video-wrapper");
    videoWrapper.classList.add("slide");
    return videoWrapper;
  }

  function showVideo(videoWrapper) {
    const thewrap = videoWrapper.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const videoWrapper = fadeVideoIn(cover);
    showVideo(videoWrapper);
    cover.dispatchEvent(events.afterClickCover);
  }

  function init(callback) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    events.afterClickCover = new Event("afterClickCover");
    cover.addEventListener("afterClickCover", callback);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());
```

Comment: I tried, and nothing is clickable in the code example, so I did not do that. Only clickable outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah, the code is using cookies behind the scenes. You can do `hide(cover); hide(videoWrapper)`

Comment: It's not working? https://jsfiddle.net/93yp7hr0/

Comment: `function fadeVideoIn(cover) {
  hide(cover);
  const videoWrapper = document.querySelector(".video-wrapper");
  hide( videoWrapper);`

Comment: I only want the Green image to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try add `background: unset;` to .video-wrapper.slide::after class

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y1uesjk8/1/

Answer (score 0):

for your issue, it is easier to make the green background with the button as the same component.

The reason why the green background doesn't get away:
It is set up as a pseudo-class under video-wrapper
In my experience, javascript can't reach a pseudo-class, even if it is possible, it will make your code super messy and hard to read and follow.

Suggestion:
Remove the green background from the video wrapper class and move it to the button.
[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Kinng_96/h1zjnuLo/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                <div class="video video-frame"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="play">
    <button type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.play {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.play button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  animation: rotate 700ms linear forwards;
  border-color: red transparent red transparent;
}

.play::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ShS6nAO.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  99.9% {
    border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: blue;
  }
}

.play button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);

}

.play button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.play button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  animation: triangle 700ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes triangle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I only want the play button to be clickable, not the image.

Comment: Hi, could you check this? https://jsfiddle.net/The_Kinng_96/h1zjnuLo/16/ , I have updated the code. It should work as you requested. In my opinion, you are doing the functionality with too many layers, it could be easier. I didn't edit too much, just adding some more layers to make the feature works. Hope it is what you need.

Comment: Your code is still broken, try and fix it.

Comment: Are you able to fix your code so it looks like this? https://jsfiddle.net/L8w6rhz4/